# How to deal with MySql ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table?

Tags: mysql

I am constantly get the following error message:

> 1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I have tried the following:

1. `sudo service mysql stop` (Went fine)
2. `sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &` (Went fine)
3. `mysql -u root` (Went fine)
4. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` (Went fine)
5. `SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');` (I get the following error:)

   ```
   ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table

   mysql> select User from mysql.user;

   +------------------+

   | User             |

   +------------------+

   | linux            |

   | root             |

   | debian-sys-maint |

   +------------------+

   3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

Comment: where do you get the error? in your log? in your app? in your website? in you terminal?

Comment: In my terminal, after login in mysql

Comment: So you type a command? what command? please add this information t your question.

Comment: As per my description above, I am unable to login into the mysql server, so I am trying to modify the password. when I type the folloing command:

 SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');

get the following error:

 ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table

Therefore I am unable to modify the password and to login into phpmyadmin page.

Hope is that clear.

Comment: Anyone ?? Issue still exist!

Comment: You can't login because your password isn't correct. Your password isn't correct because you can't change it. You can't change it because your user doesn't exist. Did you check if the user exists? For instance ` root@'localhost'` is different from ` root@'%'`

Comment: Thats weird! I tried to reinstal phpmyadmin and during the installation I chosed the password for root requested by the installation wizard... how can I check if the user or any other user exist?

Comment: check the `user` table of the `mysql` database

Comment: Apologise for the late reply. I am unable to check the user table of the mysql database as when I try to login with [mysql -u root -p] or [mysql -u root] I get:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Using the same password chosen during the reinstallation of phpmyadmin ...

Comment: Do you mean that you *can* enter the query you posted in step 5, but you cannot check the user table at that point?

Comment: I am sorry, you`re right. I forgot to stop mysql service. I am now into the mysql prompt. Here is the output of [select User from mysql.user;]

mysql> select User from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| User             |
+------------------+
| linux            |
| root             |
| debian-sys-maint |
+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: please add this to the question, because it formats better, and it also helps other passer-bys. Now please select not only the user, but everything. It is the combination of host and user we are interested in.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a mysql expert, can you please tell me how to select everything?

Comment: use `select *` instead of `select User`.

Comment: Done that, whats next?

Comment: you are updating a row that should have host `localhost` and user `root`. is it in there? (or: show the results so we can do the next step)

Comment: I get a bunch of characters, lines, and also:

| localhost | debian-sys-maint | *86CBBCDAB829505DC314D71774BFF13B3CADF719
| 127.0.0.1 | root             | *7C35BEBC1306CDBA9BE95B5F13CA85FAAAFE523F
| %         | linux            | *7C35BEBC1306CDBA9BE95B5F13CA85FAAAFE523F

I dont see how can I fix the login ?

Comment: This has been answered on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914571/1045-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

you are updating the password for a user that has name `root` and location `localhost`. From your result of your user table I conclude that there is NO such line. There seems to be a line with `root` and `127.0.0.1`, so therefore you probably need this line.

```
    SET PASSWORD FOR root@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('password');
```

Please try and understand what the difference between the two lines is, and why this should be done instead of the former: I hope this helps you see what was wrong and why you should do this, as it might be not spot-on: the comment-additions would be much easier to read if they are in the question, and formatted correctly :D

Comment: Thanks, I would really like to put in here nicely and formatted, but this field does not allow me to do it...btw, I am getting this output after I run [SET PASSWORD FOR root@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('password');]:


No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server

Comment: That's why I mentioned you should put extra information in your question (and using the buttons and the preview there, you can achieve better formatting :)  )

Comment: by the way: I think you might have a different problem then the one you posted here: the set-up of your system isn't correct, and you have googled some sort of solution that is not necessarily the best. This is called the xy problem (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ). It's hardish to help you like this, so I don't know how much further we can get ...

Comment: Thanks for the 'nice' scenario xy, the thing is that I did not touch anything, I had a clean install of mysql, apache and php and I cannot login. Now you are telling me that "the set-up of your system isn't correct" ?? I dont get this!! I post in here to find help as it might be something else and you guys are the one who can (suppose to) help !! By the way: Nice for the other passer-bys!

Comment: That's exactly what I mean: your problem seems to be "I installed mysql, and now I get this error." You did not specify where you got this, what you did, but you did specify your sollution, that ended in another error. I am trying to help you fix this error (by telling you that you should change that last line to include a user that exists), but I think the initial problem should have been the focus. Anyway, I have done my best to help you but I'm not "supposed to" help, I was just trying to be nice. good luck to you.